# python - Quickly search the dict in the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have many dictionaries in a list, like below:

```
mylist = [{'name': 'Delivered-To', 'value': '123'},
          {'name': 'Received', 'value': 'abc'},
          {'name': 'Payload', 'value': 'xxxxxx'}]
```

How can I quickly get the value of name is a parameter.

ex : if I hope to get name is 'Received', and get the dictionary:

```
{'name': 'Received', 'value': 'abc'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd build a lookup dictionary at first:

```
mylist = [{'name': 'Delivered-To', 'value': '123'},
          {'name': 'Received', 'value': 'abc'},
          {'name': 'Payload', 'value': 'xxxxxx'}]

lookup_dict = dict((d['name'], d['value']) for d in mylist)

>>> print lookup_dict
{'Received': 'abc', 'Delivered-To': '123', 'Payload': 'xxxxxx'}

>>> print lookup_dict['Received']
abc
```

Of course, this works if there are no duplicate names.

Alternative syntax:

```
lookup_dict = {d['name']: d['value']  for d in mylist}
```

Answer (score 5):

A list comprehension would work. This will provide a list of all dictionaries where `d['name'] == 'Received'`:

```
[x for x in mylist if x['name'] == 'Received']
```

Answer (score 1):

[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is the pythonic way, but this is just another option using [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
list(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == 'Received', mylist))
# [{'name': 'Received', 'value': 'abc'}]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> result = filter(lambda x: x['name'] == 'Received', mylist)
>>> result
<filter object at 0x00000198FF419C88>
>>> next(result)
{'name': 'Received', 'value': 'abc'}
```